# Continuing dynamic expansion after first expansion

Tags: emacs, expansion

Consider the situation when I have `counts.get` above me in the buffer and I want to write it again.

I would type `c` and hit the dynamic expansion keys. It would then make "counts" for me.

However, when I want to continue, I have to write "`.`" and then I can again expand to `counts.get`. This is because when expanding to "`counts`", hitting the dynamic expansion again will instead suggest a different word instead of continue.

Is there a way to follow up a dynamic expansion such that if I knew I'd want to get like `object.counts.get` I could hit dynamic expansion after typing '`o`' and 2 more keys to get the same result?

Comment: I suspect you're referring to `dabbrev-expand` (bound to `M-/` by default). This is a general-purpose completion tool; it sounds like you want a more intelligent, language-specific completion tool. What language(s) are you working in?

Comment: @Chris Actually, dabbrev should not be underestimated (it reads from any buffer and thus it is easy to copy things unknown to e.g. pylint and others, but also it suggest first the thing closest to current point, which is often the thing you want to write). I have python in mind but I think it counts for anything.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that `dabbrev` isn't useful, but I've had the best luck using it in conjunction with language-specific tools. There are several tools for Python that might help, including `jedi` and `rope`.

Comment: If after `dabbrev-expand` you hit space and then `dabbrev-expand` again, it continues the expansion from where it left off.

Answer (score 2):

You've received one suggestion, from Chris: to use language-specific expansion/completion.

Another suggestion is to use **`C-M-/`** (`dabbrev-completion`) instead of `M-/` (`dabbrev-expand`).  That shows you the possible completions and lets you choose the one you want directly.

Of course, to choose a candidate you will need to type some more keys.

Or else use a better completion system, such as that provided by [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles).  In that case, it is easy to grab the completion you want without a lot of typing.  You can use more economic matching (type less) or you can cycle among matching candidates.